# Access to Backlog unavailable post TFS 2017 RC1 upgrade

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-2017

The tfs backlog page throws the following error : "TF400898: An Internal Error Occured." after upgrading to TFS 2017 RC1 from TFS 2015. All the other contents are in tact (ie Code, Build and Test). This error occurs for all the team projects in the Team Collection. Upgrade to tfs 2017 RC1 was successful without any errors.

Error logged in event viewer:

```
TF53010: The following error has occurred in a Team Foundation component or extension:
Date (UTC): 1/30/2017 12:47:55 PM
Machine: TFS01
Application Domain: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT/tfs-1-131302443521960468
Assembly: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a; v4.0.30319
Service Host: 4fc1f4bf-8005-4244-a66c-c57edf4df7f1 (<Team Project Collection>)
Process Details:
  Process Name: w3wp
  Process Id: 18288
  Thread Id: 36708
  Account name: <Domain>\<User>

Detailed Message: TF30065: An unhandled exception occurred.

Web Request Details
    Url: http://<TfsServer>:8080/tfs/<TeamProjectCollection>/<TeamProject>/Application/_backlogs [method: GET]
    User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; InfoPath.3)
    Headers: not available
    Path: /tfs/<TeamProjectCollection>/<TeamProject>/Application/_backlogs
    Local Request: True
    Host Address: fe80::a8d5:ecb7:9ff9:640c%13
    User: <Domain>\<User> [authentication type: Negotiate]

Exception Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. (type NullReferenceException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WebAccess.WorkItemTracking.Common.BacklogConfigurationService.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<GetBacklogConfiguration>b__0()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.VssRequestContextExtensions.TraceBlock[T](IVssRequestContext requestContext, Int32 enterTracepoint, Int32 leaveTracepoint, Int32 exceptionTracepoint, String area, String layer, String methodName, Func`1 action)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WebAccess.WorkItemTracking.Common.BacklogConfigurationService.GetBacklogConfiguration(IVssRequestContext requestContext, Guid projectId, TeamFoundationTeam team, Boolean validateProcessConfig)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Agile.Server.AgileSettings..ctor(IVssRequestContext requestContext, CommonStructureProjectInfo project, TeamFoundationTeam team)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WebAccess.Agile.AgileAreaController.get_Settings()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WebAccess.Agile.BacklogsController.get_RequestBacklogContext()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WebAccess.Agile.BacklogsController.Index(String level, Nullable`1 showParents)
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: Same issue reported in MSDN forum at  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/96e7776a-abdb-4378-9e7e-17aacdb53d6b/unable-to-access-backlogs-for-particular-team-project-after-upgrading-from-tfs-2017-to-tfs-2017?forum=tfsworkitemtracking

Comment: Did this error only occurs with IE? Did you give a try with another browser such as chrome or firefox ?

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT The error occurs both on IE and Chrome

Comment: Did this error occurs on this special team project  or  all projects? Did you give a try with re-running the configuration wizard in my answer which may did the trick.

Comment: @patrick-MSFT This error was specific to one particular team project, we did try running the configuration wizard but it was not successful. Following was the message post running the configuration wizard "There are no process templates available with valid configuration settings for this team project"

Comment: @Santhosh Certain work item types (WITs) and categories are required for the wizard to configure a feature. If you have renamed or deleted any of these WITs or categories, the wizard will return the following messages.

Comment: You will have to **rename** or **reinstate** the missing WITs or categories to your team project, and then rerun the wizard. Or, you can **modify the process templates** to add the features and then rerun the wizard.

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT Thanks, will try to implement the suggestions.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it looks like this was a Release Candidate issue for a product released 7 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

If the upgrade was successful without any errors. Then this kind of issue may related to the configuration.

You could try **re-running the configuration wizard** for the team project to fix the issue. How to please refer this tutorial: [Configure features after an upgrade](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/customize/configure-features-after-upgrade)